# How to show that this ring has no zero divisors?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a finite ring that satisfies the following conditions:

(1) For any $x\in R$, if $x\ne 0$ then $x^2\ne 0$.

(2) There exists at most one nonzero element $y\in R$ that satisfies $y^2=y$.

How can we show that $R$ has no zero divisors?

Comment: **Please** do not delete questions and reask them anew: you can *edit* them.

Comment: This seems to be a homework problem or one out of a book. If that is the case, it is useful that you tell us where it is from, and ideally what you have tried, where you get stuck and other information that will help people help you!   
It also helps to know if you are thinking about commutative rings and/or rings with unit

Comment: I don't know where it come from. This problem is given by a friend of me. He don't know either.

Comment: Ah! The Problem That Came Out of Nowhere. There ought to be a Holmes story with  title like that :-)

Comment: If the ring is commutative the question ammounts to prove the ring is, in fact, a field. Knowing this perhaps can give some insight, yet the answer Mariano wrote below gives a general solution without assuming commutativity.

Answer (score 6):

From what you write, it is impossible to know what you know, so this may be incomprehensible to you, but here it goes. I will assume the ring has a unit.

Since $R$ is finite, it is Artinian. Its Jacobson radical $J(R)$ is therefore nilpotent, so in particular its elements are themselves nilpotent: in view of your first hypothesis, $J(R)=0$ and the ring is in fact semisimple. The theorem of Artin-Wedderburn tells us that $R$ is a direct product of matrix rings over division rings. Since there is only one idempotent, the product can at most contain one factor, and the size of the matrices in that factor must be one. We thus see that $R$ itself is a division ring.

Comment: I don't see how (1) rules out that $x^3=0$.

Comment: If there is a non-zero nilpotent element $x$, there is a non-zero element whose square is zero: just take a power $x^k$ such that $x^k\neq0$ but $x^{2k}=0$.

Comment: Ah, of course. Extra characters.